# Why doesn't X-0 match with 20?

Tags: prolog, unification

I have the following fact in my knowledge base: `distance(c2, c5, 20, 1)`.

But when I try to query `distance(c2, c5, X-0, 1)`, (or any other number instead of 0), this returns false. Why is that? Shouldn't X just bind to 20 since 20-0=20?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prolog interprets that as a [term](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=manipterm) with functor name `dash` and arity `2` - evidence:

```
?- Term = X-0, Term = -(X, 0), functor(Term, Name, Arity).
Term = X-0,
Name = (-),
Arity = 2.
```

Use e.g. [is](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=is/2) for arithmetic:

```
?- X = 5, Y is X - 0.
X = Y, Y = 5.

?- X = 5, Y is X-0.
X = Y, Y = 5.
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. But why then does `Y is X-0, distance(c2, c5, Y, 1).` give an error that variables are not properly instantiated?

Comment: I found that doing Y #= X-0, distance(c2, c5, Y, 1) gave me the answer I wanted.

Comment: Can't calculate X minus zero, when X is undefined. X must be given a value ("instantiated") first.